# como se deshabilita el contenido de una columna de una tabla

Tags: jquery

Tengo una tabla, cuyas filas se van agregando en forma dinámica.

Cada columna tiene elementos del tipo `select` e `input text` y la última columna tiene un texto `"Eliminar"`, de modo que cuando el usuario da *click* en dicha columna, se elimina la fila.

¿Cómo puedo deshabilitar dicho "Eliminar" de modo que al dar clic no se elimine la fila?

Esto trabajando con `jquery`.

La columna tiene la forma:

```
<td  class="eliminar">
    Eliminar
</td>
```

La tercera columna es:

```
<td  class="eliminar">
    Eliminar
</td>
```

Cuando se da click a esta columna, se gatilla lo siguiente:

```
$(document).on("click",".eliminar",function()
{
var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
var fila=$(parent).attr('id');
$(parent).remove();
}
```

La pregunta apunta a si existe algún atributo a nivel de columna que se pueda resetear de modo que se deshabilite el contenido y no se ejecuten las acciones cuando se da click.

Por ejemplo, los elementos de las columnas anteriores los he deshabilitado de la siguiente forma:

```
$("#tabla tbody tr").each(function () 
{   
$(this).find("td:eq(0)").find("select").attr('disabled',true);  
$(this).find("td:eq(1)").find("input").attr('disabled',true);
$(this).find("td:eq(2)").attr('disabled',true);
}
```

enla última línea muestro cómo estoy tratando de deshabilitar el contenido de la columna, pero no funciona.

Les comento que solucioné el tema haciendo lo siguiente:

```
$("#tabla tbody tr").each(function () 
{   
$(this).find("td:eq(0)").find("select").attr('disabled',true);  
$(this).find("td:eq(1)").find("input").attr('disabled',true);
$(this).find("td:eq(2)").removeClass("eliminar");
```

De esa forma, al dar clic en esa columna, al no tener la clase, no se ejecutan las acciones en:

```
$(document).on("click",".eliminar",function()
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar algo más de código? ¿Le introduces alguna función a ese texto?

Comment: Hola @Junco. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! La verdad, te recomiendo generar un ejemplo como el descripto en [mcve], de modo que sea más sencillo entender tu pregunta, y no estar interpretando cuál sería la estructura de la tabla por lo que comentás.

Comment: Hola @Mariano. Tomaré en cuenta tu recomendación; como soy nuevo en Stack Overflow en español, aun estoy conociendo las reglas que permiten un mejor resultado. Gracias.

Comment: En resumen, si te ayuda un poco más, me olvidaría de cómo se genera dinámicamente la tabla, y agregaría un ejemplo de código simplificado de cómo se ve la tabla en un cliente. Es irrelevante (creo) para la pregunta todo lo previo. Lo importante es ver un ejemplo simple y una pregunta concisa. Ejemplo: *Tengo esta tabla `<tabla>`, ¿cómo hago para que al hacer `<esto>` pase `<aquello>`? probé `<así>`, pero no funciona porque espero `<esto otro>` *

Comment: Perfecto, tomo tu consejo y gracias,

Answer (score 0):

con este código puede funcionar, si das click en la primera columna no es posible hacer click ahí. Simplemente debes añadir esa clase en el item en donde no quieres que se elimine la fila. Esa clase se recomienda añadirla en el momento en que se crea la tabla o bien en base a otro criterio después de haber sido creada.

```js
$("tr td:nth-child(3)").click(function(){
     if (!$(this).hasClass("not-active")){
         alert("El item sera eliminado.");
         // tu codigo para eliminar aqui
    }
});
```

```css
.not-active {
   cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>nombre</th>
            <th>apellido</th> 
            <th>X</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr> 
          <td>juan</td>
          <td>perez</td>
          <td class="not-active">eliminar</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
              <td>Jose</td>
              <td>Lopez</td>
              <td>eliminar</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
              <td>Mary</td>
              <td>Lopez</td>
              <td>eliminar</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Recomendación: deberías de añadir algo de explicación al texto para que el OP pueda entender lo que quieres realizar o cómo esto le puede ayudar.

Comment: @Error404 si, estaba editando, solo decidí añadir primero el código

Comment: He añadido más información en el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Comment: ya no tiene que ver nada con la pregunta original

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres que se elimine, tal vez podrías sustituir el link con un "#",

```
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/" class="testClick">Home</a>

$(".testClick").click(function () {
        var value = $( this ).attr( "href" ); // Obtener el valor del atributo href
        alert( value ); // mostrar ese valor obtenido
        value = $( this ).attr( "href", "#" ); // asignar nuevo valor a href
        alert( value ); // mostrar nuevo valor
        return false; // evitar el envío
    });
```

A menos que no haya yo entendido correctamente, podría ser una opción.

Answer (score -1):

Ocúltala de la vista del usuario con `visibility` Esto provocará que ocupe el espacio como si realmente estuviera allí, útil si algunas celdas si se deben mostrar basadas en requisitos.

```
<td  class="eliminar" style="visibility: hidden;">
Eliminar
</td>
```

Si quieres ocultar TODAS, mejor usa la clase para hacerlo

```
<style>
.eliminar{
    /*Usa cualquiera de estas, dependiendo de como que se vea tu UI*/
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Sinceramente, no creo que el OP de la suficiente información como para saber que tipo de evento lanza el texto Eliminar cuando le da click.

Comment: He añadido más información en el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Por que el voto negativo?